# How to get a document library URL from c# in visual web part?

Tags: development, list, document-library, visual-web-part, url

I'm making a visual webpart in a sp2010 environment. I am trying to get the document library URL. I have this code so far:

My variables are not getting the right values. Like the `libraryURL`, `librarySiteRelativeURL`, `libraryNewFormURL`, `libraryNewFolderURL`, `librarySettingsURL`.

For example if the library was located here:

`http://mydomain/en/Information/admin/IS/RD/Pages/mylibrary` where `/en...` is a site collection, then I would like:

```
libraryURL = http://mydomain/en/Information/admin/IS/RD/Pages/mylibrary
librarySiteRelativeURL = /en/Information/admin/IS/RD/Pages/mylibrary
etc...
(librarySettingsURL is the settings page of the library)
```

code:

```
        context = SPContext.Current;
        web = context.Web;
        site = context.Site;

        webURL = web.Url;
        siteURL = site.Url;
        pageURL = webURL + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
        pageURLWithoutQuery = (new Uri(pageURL)).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);

        try
        {
            // get the list
            library = (SPDocumentLibrary)web.GetList(webpartObject.SHAREPOINT_LIST);
            libraryURL = siteURL + "/" + library.RootFolder.Url;
            libraryName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(libraryURL);
            librarySiteRelativeURL = siteURL + library.ParentWebUrl;
            libraryNewFormURL = webURL + "/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={" + library.ID + "}&RootFolder=/" + libraryName;
            libraryNewFolderURL = libraryURL + "/Forms/Upload.aspx?RootFolder=/" + libraryName + "&Type=1&IsDlg=1";
            librarySettingsURL = siteURL + "/_layouts/listedit.aspx?List={" + library.ID + "}";

            fileOrderProperty = webpartObject.ORDER_PROPERTY_NAME;
        }
        catch
        {
            library = null;
        }
```

Does anyone know the right way of getting these links?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When working with URLs in SharePoint, there are two very helpful utility classes: [SPUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and [SPUrlUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.spurlutility%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

There are three different kinds of url used in different properties of various SharePoint objects: absolute, server-relative and site-relative. One need to be careful with them, especially when site collection is not located directly at web application root url.

In order to get list/library url from SPList object, the following method could be used (examples):

```
var web = SPContext.Current.Web;
var webAbsoluteUrl = web.Url;
var library = web.GetList("<Server-relative url needed here, not site relative as documentation says>");
var libraryAbsoluteUrl = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(webAbsoluteUrl, library.RootFolder.Url);
var libraryServerRelativeUrl = library.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl;
var libraryUploadFormUrl = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(webAbsoluteUrl, string.Format("/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={0}", library.ID));
var libraryNewFolderServerRelativeUrl = string.Format("{0}?RootFolder={1}&Type=1", library.DefaultNewFormUrl, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(library.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl));
var libraryNewFolderAbsoluteUrl = SPUtility.GetFullUrl(SPContext.Current.Site, libraryNewFolderServerRelativeUrl);
var librarySettingsUrl = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(webAbsoluteUrl, string.Format("/_layouts/listedit.aspx?List={0}", library.ID));
```